# Passing pointer into function, data appears initialized in function, on return appears uninitialized

Tags: c, pointers, time

I'm passing function `GetCurrentDate()` the pointer to a tm struct.  Within that function I printf the uninitialized data, then the initialized. Expected results.

However when I return the tm struct appears uninitialized. See console output below. What am I doing wrong?

> uninitialized date:??? ???-1073908332
>   01:9448278:-1073908376 -1217355836
>
> initialized date:Wed May  5 23:08:40
>   2010
>
> Caller date:??? ???-1073908332
>   01:9448278:-1073908376 -121735583

```
int main()
{
    test(); 
}

int test()
{
    struct tm* CurrentDate;
    GetCurrentDate(CurrentDate);
    printf("Caller date:%s\n",asctime (CurrentDate));
    return 1;
}

int GetCurrentDate(struct tm* p_ReturnDate)
{ 
    printf("uninitialized date:%s\n",asctime (p_ReturnDate));
    time_t m_TimeEntity;
    m_TimeEntity = time(NULL); //setting current time into a time_t struct

    p_ReturnDate = localtime(&m_TimeEntity); //converting time_t to tm struct
    printf("initialized date:%s\n",asctime (p_ReturnDate));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm quite surprised the program didn't crash outright when you used the uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are updating the pointer p_ReturnDate in the function, not updating the structure that p_ReturnDate points to. Because the pointer is passed by value, the update doesn't affect the caller.

Also as pointed out by [Joseph Quinsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777181/passing-pointer-into-function-data-appears-initialized-in-function-on-return-a/2777217#2777217) you need to provide a place to put the result. You're only allocating a pointer in the caller, not the whole structure.

Answer (score 5):

In test(), you need to actually specify memory to store the data. For example;

```
struct tm CurrentDate;
GetCurrentDate(&CurrentDate);
printf("Caller date:%s\n",asctime(&CurrentDate));
```

Comment: Yes, the dreaded two-bug design pattern, as Mark Ranson points out.

Comment: "The dreaded two-bug design pattern" - that's great, I'll have to remember that one! I'm surprised the GOF didn't cover it in their book, it's popular enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
int
main()
{
    test(); 
}

void
test()
{
    struct tm CurrentDate;

    GetCurrentDate(&CurrentDate);
    printf("Caller date:%s\n", asctime(&CurrentDate));
}

void
GetCurrentDate(struct tm* p_ReturnDate)
{ 
    time_t m_TimeEntity;

    printf("uninitialized date:%s\n", asctime(p_ReturnDate));    
    m_TimeEntity = time(NULL); //setting current time into a time_t struct
    *p_ReturnDate = *localtime(&m_TimeEntity); //converting time_t to tm struct    
    printf("initialized date:%s\n", asctime (p_ReturnDate));
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's best to let someone figure things out on their own. Sometimes they need to see the answer before they can understand. It's a fine line.